# Sort drop-down menu data with Haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this on one of my views. Can anyone here help me figure out how I can sort the data that is being passed in? I need to be able to organize the data in a very specific way, so sorting by asc or desc order won't help here. Does anyone know how this could be accomplished? If so, is there a guide that shows where it'd go? I've tried multiple things and nothing seems to work. Maybe I have the wrong approach?

```
- fields = %w(title description)
- sortable = %w(title)

= render :partial => 'shared/index', :locals => { :klass => PermissionGroup, :objects => @permission_groups, :fields => fields, :sortable => sortable }
```

This is what I have in the controller:

```
class PermissionGroupsController < ApplicationController
 standard_controller_actions :index
 standard_controller_actions :show
 standard_controller_actions :new, :create
 standard_controller_actions :edit, :update
 standard_controller_actions :destroy
 standard_controller_actions :autocomplete
 standard_controller_actions :history
 standard_controller_actions :url_list
end
```

And this is what I have on the helper:

```
module PermissionsHelper

def objects_permission_groups(object)

  if object.new_record? and
    permission_groups_with_create = current_user.permission_groups_with(:create) and
   permission_groups_with_create.count == 1
    object_permission_groups = permission_groups_with_create
  else
    object_permission_groups = object.permission_group_ids
  end
 object_permission_groups
end

def permission_group_options(_)
 PermissionGroup.all.map { |g| [g.title.titleize, g.id.to_s] }
end
```

The drop down menu displays:

```
b
c
d
a
x
```

but I want it to display:

```
x
d
a
c
b
```

It's not asc or desc order... Just as a known set of things that I want to sort in a hard-coded way.

Comment: Question is not very clear but I suppose you want to sort @permission_groups. You need to do that in the controller. Can you post it?

Comment: Please give us more information - an example or two would be good (eg some sample data and different ways you'd expect to see it sorted... what it would look like when it's sorted etc). That will help us get a better understanding of what you want and then we can make suggestions.

Comment: @TopperH - Done. Apologies for not adding it from the beginning.

Comment: @Taryn East - Added

Comment: arbitrary... so you have a known set of things you want to sort in a specific, hard-coded way? or you want to sort them randomly? If the former, then you can add a column to your table called `sort_order` and store your hard-coded sort-order on each item... and then sort based on that if the latter, then look at random sorting in database columns

Comment: @Taryn East: Arbitrary as a known set of things I want to sort in a hard-coded way, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to hard-code a specific sort-order, the way I've seen this solved most fequently is to:

a) add an integer `sort_order` column to your model's database table

b) populate that with the sort order for the items (eg x would have value 1, d would have value 2 and so on) - which you could do via a migration if you want it to be deployable to your production server

c) order by that column ascending...

Future nice-interfaces would let you edit the sort-order in the browser eg with drag/drop javascript (or just typing in the numbers by hand).